# How I can use FlexyPool with a custom DataSourceFactory?

Tags: tomcat, java-8, guice, tomcat-dbcp, flexy-pool

I have a simple Tomcat application setup to use a MySQL data source with a custom `DataSourceFactory`. The `context.xml` is give below. The custom factory is used merely to the placeholders (`{{driver}}`) with actual values at runtime.

```xml
<Context displayName="Foo" path="/foo">
    <Resource name="jdbc/MySQLDB"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="{{maxTotal}}"
              maxIdle="{{maxIdle}}"
              ...
              driverClassName="{{driver}}"
              username="{{user}}"
              password="{{password}}"
              url="{{url}}"
              factory="com.example.CustomDataSourceFactory" />
</Context>
```

The application uses [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) to inject `DataSource` instances:

```java
bind(DataSource.class).toProvider(fromJndi(DataSource.class, "java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDB"));
```

How can I wrap my MySQL `DataSource` using a [flexy-pool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) `FlexyPoolDataSource`?

I checked out the [documentation](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool/wiki/Java-EE-Configuration) and did the following:

1. Added the necessary dependencies (`flexy-pool-core`, `flexy-java-ee`)
2. Added a `flexy-pool.properties` file at resources root (contents below)

```
flexy.pool.data.source.unique.name=flexy-pool-dataSource
flexy.pool.data.source.jndi.name=jdbc/MySQLDB
flexy.pool.metrics.reporter.jmx.auto.start=true
```

I'm stuck - how can I make the `CustomDataSourceFactory` work with `flexy-pool`?
What should I change and how?

Comment: FWIW the `CustomDataSourceFactory` extends `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory`

Comment: Solution: currently the `CustomDataSourceFactory` is returning an instance of `DataSource`. Wrap it in `FlexyPoolDataSource` and return the wrapped instance instead. Now trying to figure out how to observe metrics.